# Multiplication of transpositions?

Tags: permutations

I can't seem to understand how the multiplication of two transpositions yield the results below:

$(x b)(x a) = (x a)(a b) \\
(c a)(x a) = (x c)(c a)$

I can't figure it out for the life of me. I'm trying to learn permutation multiplication on my own, and I feel confident in my abilities, but here I feel as though I'm missing something essential. Could someone please enlighten me as to the process (in depth) of multiplying these transpositions and getting the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume $a$, $b$ and $x$ to be distinct.

The trick for computing the composition of permutations is to start from an arbitrary element, say $x$, and follow its image under the permutations to compose; then write the final element next to $x$ and go on. If an element doesn't appear in a cycle, it is fixed by it. The image of an element under a cycle is the element next to it (on the right) or the initial one if at the right there's a `)`.

For instance, the cycle $(xa)$ represents the permutation that sends $x$ to $a$, $a$ to $x$ and leaves all other elements fixed.

Depending on conventions you start from the left or from the right; when composition of functions is the usual one, one starts from the right; so with $(xb)(xa)$

$x\mapsto a\mapsto a$
$a\mapsto x\mapsto b$
$b\mapsto b\mapsto x$

When we get back to the element we started with, we stop the cycle and start again if there's still an uncovered element. In this case we obtain the cycle $(xab)$.

If we consider $(xa)(ab)$ we get

$x\mapsto x\mapsto a$
$a\mapsto b\mapsto b$
$b\mapsto a\mapsto x$

So the composition is again the cycle $(xab)$ and we've proved equality.

Comment: How come you started from the left for $(x a)(a b)$?

Comment: @cbutler16 No, I started from the right; under $(ab)$ the image of $x$ is $x$.

Comment: But for $(x a)(a b)$, $a$ goes to $b$, $b$ goes to $a$, and finally $a$ goes to $x$. So wouldn't you have the permutation $( a b x)$ if you began multiplying from the right?

Comment: Oh never mind I see it now!! Thank you very much!! 

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, suppose the only elements in the set are in fact $a,b,x$ for the first case.  Try writing each as a single permutation.

$(x~b)(x~a)$ read from right to left says:

$\begin{array}{c}a\mapsto x\mapsto b\\ x\mapsto a\mapsto a\\ b\mapsto b\mapsto x\end{array}$

I.e. $(x~b)(x~a) = \begin{pmatrix}a&b&x\\b&x&a\end{pmatrix}$

On the other hand, $(x~a)(a~b)$ read from right to left says:

$\begin{array}{c}a\mapsto b\mapsto b\\ b\mapsto a\mapsto x\\ x\mapsto x\mapsto a\end{array}$

So we have $(x~a)(a~b)=\begin{pmatrix} a&b&x\\b&x&a\end{pmatrix}$

These are indeed equal.  We have then $(x~b)(x~a)= (x~a)(a~b)$

Try reading through the second example to see if it is true.